# No output in asynchronous functions using F#?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

Tried to implement a reader-writer problem using Blocking Queue with the code given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297096.aspx).
   The entire thing compiled and runs, but the portions within async{...} in the reader() and writer() functions are producing no output whatsoever. I'm pretty sure they are being called properly, because even though I'm a noob with F# the tutorial page with this code seemed authentic.

Here's the whole code:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Collections.Generic
//open System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

///defining Agent
type Agent<'T> = MailboxProcessor<'T>

///defining Message
type internal BlockingAgentMessage<'T> = 
  | Get of AsyncReplyChannel<'T>
  | Add of 'T * AsyncReplyChannel<unit> 

/// Agent-based implementation of producer/consumer problem 
type BlockingQueueAgent<'T>(maxLength) =
    let agent = Agent.Start(fun agent ->
        let queue = new Queue<_>()
        //let queue = new Queue()
        // State machine running inside the agent
        let rec emptyQueue() = 
            agent.Scan(fun msg ->
                match msg with 
                | Add(value, reply) -> Some(enqueueAndContinue(value, reply))
                | _ -> None )
        and fullQueue() = 
            agent.Scan(fun msg ->
                match msg with 
                | Get(reply) -> Some(dequeueAndContinue(reply))
                | _ -> None )
        and runningQueue() = async {
            let! msg = agent.Receive() 
            match msg with 
            | Add(value, reply) -> return! enqueueAndContinue(value, reply)
            | Get(reply) -> return! dequeueAndContinue(reply) }
        and enqueueAndContinue (value, reply) = async {
            queue.Enqueue(value)
            reply.Reply() 
            return! chooseState() }
        and dequeueAndContinue (reply) = async { 
            reply.Reply(queue.Dequeue())
            return! chooseState() }
        and chooseState() = 
            if queue.Count = 0 then emptyQueue()
            elif queue.Count = maxLength then fullQueue()
            else runningQueue()

        // Start with an empty queue
        emptyQueue() )

    /// Asynchronously adds item to the queue. If the queue
    /// is full, it blocks until some items are removed.
    member x.AsyncAdd(v:'T) = 
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply(fun ch -> Add(v, ch))

    /// Asynchronously gets item from the queue. If the queue
    /// is empty, it blocks until some items are added.
    member x.AsyncGet() = 
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply(Get)




let ag = new BlockingQueueAgent<int>(3)
printfn "Blocking Queue Agent program"

let writer() = async {

    for i in 0 .. 10 do 
        do! ag.AsyncAdd(i)
        printfn "Added: %d" i }

let reader () = async { 
    while true do
        let! v = ag.AsyncGet()
        do! Async.Sleep(1000)
        printfn "Got: %d" v }

reader () |> Async.Start
printfn "Started Reader ..."
writer () |> Async.Start
printfn "Started Writer ..."
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the code is fine - your program is just exiting before the `async` can execute.  Just add something like

```
System.Console.Read() |> ignore
```

to the end.  This works for me

Comment: ah like the getch() in the good old days of C! being a noob in f# sure has its downsides. thanks.